# How to make my javascript in my Chrome Extension only run after element is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome Extension that is able to change images of banner icons on a page. The .js waits for the window.onload to issue, then starts a mutationObserver for the div that contains the banners. If a change is detected, a for loop changes all the images.

My issue is that the mutationObserver is run before the div exists, meaning I run into a `Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'` error.

How can I guarantee that this element has fully loaded in before my code executes?

I'm also having an issue where if I navigate the page and come back to the page with the banners, my code does not run. I believe this is caused by my "window.onload" function.

Here's my code for the chrome extension. Thank ya'll!

```
window.onload = () => {
        const targetNode = document.getElementById('course-columns-current');

        const config = { attributes: true, childLIst: true, subtree: true};
        
        const callback = (observer) => {
            const banners = document.getElementsByClassName("course-banner");
        
            console.log("inside the callback!")
            console.log(banners)
            
            for (let i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
                console.log(banners[i])
                banners[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=640:*')";
            }
        };
        
        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
}
```

Comment: You can observe `document.body`, no need for window.onload.

Comment: @wOxxOm worked perfectly! thank you so much for your help, can't believe I missed this.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, the solution ended up being replacing the observer target to `document.body`.

Here's the updated and working code:

```
window.onload = () => {
        const targetNode = document.body;

        const config = { attributes: true, childLIst: true, subtree: true};
        
        const callback = (observer) => {
            const banners = document.getElementsByClassName("course-banner");
        
            console.log("inside the callback!")
            console.log(banners)
            
            for (let i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
                console.log(banners[i])
                banners[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=640:*')";
            }
        };
        
        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
}
```